# Populating dropdown field with text when a row is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have HTML where I am trying to populate a drop-down with string data using jQuery when an item is selected from a drop-down.

```
                            <td class="col-md-3" colspan="4">
                                <label class="control-label">{{item.fields[11].displayName}}22</label>
                                <div class="dropdown" style="width:100%">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-ng-disabled="formReadOnly" data-ng-model="item[item.fields[11].name]" data-ng-keyup="comboBoxGenOptions(2, 148, item[item.fields[11].name], 'searchGenericOptions')" />
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="width:100%">
                                        <li class="GpiId" data-ng-repeat="name in searchGenericOptions" style="width:100%"><a data-ng-click="changeData(item.fields[11].name, name)">{{name}}</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <label class="error" data-ng-show="issueSuppNum()">Please insert a valid generic name.</label>
                                @*<div class="GenId" data-strat-form-control data-field-display-id="1" data-vmformreadonly="formReadOnly" data-show-tool-tip="showToolTip(item.fields[7].htmlName)" data-strat-model="item" data-field="item.fields[7]"></div>*@
                            </td>
```

The drop down populates with an object:

[image]

When I click it, I want to show the GPI field:

```
    $scope.changeData = function (propertyName, name) {
        $scope.item[propertyName] = name;
        $('GpiId').text(name.GPI);
    };
```

The objects are being pulled on correctly:

[image]

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Edit: added class to field.

Comment: what is the output so far?

Comment: @Roljhon [object Object] is what populates the field.

Comment: Get rid of jQuery and bootstrap.js and use angular-ui-bootstrap and angular methodology. Suggest reading [“Thinking in AngularJS” if I have a jQuery background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

Comment: There should never be any dom code in an angular controller

Comment: @charlietfl I will check out some articles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think you missed a "." in your class selector.
`$('GpiId').text(name.GPI);`

to

```
$('.GpiId').text(name.GPI);
```

Second, since you are already using angular, I would try to use {{}} within GpiId instead.

Comment: I also had to change $ to jQuery so angular doesn't get confused.